# Массив строк в С/С++

Tags: c, c++

Итак, в С/С++ массив строк мы создаем следующим образом

```
char ** ptr = new char*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    ptr[i] = new char[m];
```

В результате получаем n строк по m символов в каждой строке. Для передвижения по строке мы можем воспользоваться следующей конструкцией

```
while( ptr[i] != NULL && *ptr[i] != '\0') {
    // Делаем нечто
    ++p[i];
}
```

По сути мы смотрим, встретился ли нам символ окончания строки. Мы можем передать сроку в ф-ю без передачи ее длины, и перебрать все символы в строке. Вопрос такой, как сделать подобный механизм для перебора строк в массиве?

Comment: Вы, вообще, каким-то неблагодарным делом заниматься собираетесь :). Используйте std::vector! Если же почему-то надо именно на C, то используйте структурку из массива и его длины.

Comment: Это вопрос носит теоретический характер. Просто интересно. PS В вектор нежелательно класть другой вектор, на сколько я помню.

Comment: Вектору абсолютно без разницы, что в него класть :). Но моя позиция такова, что в обсуждаемой ситуации в вектор лучше всего класть std::string ;). Если Вы будете что-то такое писать на C++, то выбор должен быть однозначно в пользу STL'ных типом вместо сишных.

Comment: А так ответ, в общем-то, уже даден — нужно добавлять последним фейковый элемент, как это делается в сишных строках (только тут это Вам придётся делать ручками). Можно ещё для прикола попробовать вариант, схожий с паскалевскими строками, когда первым элементом массива хранится его длина :).

Answer (score 4):

Что то типа такого.

```
static char end[] = "end";
char ** ptr = new char*[n+1];
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
   ptr[i] = new char[m];
ptr[n] = end; // как альтернатива '= NULL'
```

Comment: Это я и имел в виду

Comment: Если вдруг у вас ptr[j] станет равным NULL, то такая схема сломается.

Comment: @Equinox да сломается, по этому так и не пишут, но вопрос то был "как сделать подобный механизм для перебора строк в массиве" - куда уж подобнее? строка ведь тоже оборвется если в середину поставить 0

Comment: На самом деле не обязательно зацикливаться на NULL, можно последнюю строку заменить на пару строк типа:
static char const end[] = "END"; // указатель на эту строку использовать как ноль в С строке
ptr[n] = end;

Comment: static char const end[] = "end";
char ** ptr
...
ptr[n] = end;
работать не будет, поскольку типы не соответствуют друг другу.
в примере удалил 'const', но тут разумеется тоже минусы, иногда нужно и const. На все случаи не сделаешь.

Answer (score 1):

Подобные массивы не могут ничего знать о своей длине
Как вариант можно добавить еще один элемент в массив, что-нибудь типа '\0' для строки.

P.S. '\0' в конец строки добавляется именно для обозначения ее завершения

Answer (score 0):

У вас, возможно ошибка в первом фрагменте кода?

```
char ** ptr = new char*[n];  
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {  
    ptr[i] = new char[m];  
}
```

Тогда получается, что `ptr[i]` - это указатель на i-ю строку, а `ptr[i][j]` - указатель на j-й символ i-й строки.

Если массив не разреженный, то строки (и символы в них) можно перебрать например так:

```
int i = 0;
while(ptr[i] != NULL) {
    char *curStr = prt[i]; // Текущая строка  
    int j = 0;  
    while(*currStr[j] != '\0') {
        char curChar = *currStr[j] // Текущий символ в строке  
        ...
        j++;    
    }  
    i++;  
}
```

P.S. Пока писал ответ, ошибку вы исправили)
P.S.S. Не могу разобраться, как тут форматировать код..

Comment: <pre><code> some code  </code></pre>

Comment: @1101_debian Оборачивать код тэгами необязательно. Достаточно просто добавить уровень идентации (четыре пробела). Это можно сделать или в исходном редакторе, или в форме ввода (кнопка 101010).